# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error on Post Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am getting the "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" error on form submit, but I can't figure out why. Here is my form, created with Laravel Collective form creator:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'photographer/listing/store', 'method'=>'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}

    //Bunch of Form Inputs here:

    {!!Form::submit('Create Listing')!!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then here is my route:

```
Route::post('photographer/listing/store', 'PhotographerController@storeListing');
```

And Finally, here is the controller:

```
    class PhotographerController extends Controller
{
        public function storeListing(Request $request)
          {


            //Form Validation

            //Store in the database

            return redirect('/photographer');

          }

}
```

From what I have seen, this error comes up when you use the incorrect method for the request, ex. route is a get where form is a post, but that isn't the case here, so I don't really know what is going on.

Update: I am also including the relevant information from `php artisan route:list` as well here:

```
 POST     | photographer/listing/store     |                           | App\Http\Controllers\PhotographerController@storeListing               | web,auth:photographer  
GET|HEAD | photographer                   | photographer.dashboard    | App\Http\Controllers\PhotographerController@index                      | web,auth:photographer
```

Comment: Try setting absolute url in your form. Like this `['url' => '/photographer/listing/store' ...]`. I'd even suggest you to [name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes) your routes and call them with `route(name)`.

Comment: Tried that already, didn't work.

Comment: try using url helper: `'url' => url( 'photographer/listing/store')`

Comment: @PeymanSeraj Thanks for the tip, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please try to list your routes. `php artisan route:list` . can you see your route?

Comment: @PeymanSeraj I added the relevant routes from `php artisan route:list` to my question.

Comment: I can only guess of cache problem at the moment. try clearing the cache files and test again.

Comment: @PeymanSeraj Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Have you tried to use the named parameter like this: `https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#opening-a-form`. Since the method is already `post ` you might not need to explicitely tell the `method ` when opening the form. Not sure why there is an error. The syntax looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked where that the URL on the form action is correct?

My guess is that the following line:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'photographer/listing/store', 'method'=>'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

isn't pointing to the relative URL you expect. Try adding in the forward slash in the url parameter as below:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/photographer/listing/store', 'method'=>'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}
```